# HTML, JS: hide and display input fields in dependency of selection

Tags: javascript, html, select, input, drop-down-menu

as the title says: I would like to hide and display some input fields in dependency of a selection.
This is my code, it works fine, but I am not quite happy with it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunc(){
    let id = document.getElementById("selection").value;
    if (id == "mercedes"){
        document.getElementById("mercedesBlock").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("fordBlock").style.display = "none";
    } else if (id == "ford") {
        document.getElementById("fordBlock").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("mercedesBlock").style.display = "none";
    };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selection" onchange="myFunc()">
        <option value="default">---</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="ford">Ford</option>
</select>

<div id="mercedesBlock" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" id="speed" placeholder="Speed"><br>
    <input type="text" id="seats" placeholder="number of seats">
</div>

<div id="fordBlock" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" id="electric" placeholder="Electric"><br>
    <input type="text" id="consumption" placeholder="Fuel Consumption">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are two options and for each option there are different input fields. (I know ... that example is a little bit silly.)
Because of that manual hiding and displaying, this isn't scalable.
Is there another smooth possibility to implement such a functionality (maybe with jQuery)?

I also want to hide everything, if the default option ("---") is selected.
Please keep in mind, that I'm a beginner in things like frontend development. :D

Thanks in advance! :)

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this scalable with vanilla JS. 
First hide all blocks in the DOM. Then just use the variable to find the block Element you really need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunc(){
  let id = document.getElementById("selection").value,
      blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

  for (let block of blocks) {
    block.style.display = 'none';
  }

  if ('default' !== id) {
    document.getElementById(`${id}Block`).style.display = 'block';
  }
  
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selection" onchange="myFunc()">
        <option value="default">---</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="ford">Ford</option>
</select>

<div id="mercedesBlock" class="block" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" id="speed" placeholder="Speed"><br>
    <input type="text" id="seats" placeholder="number of seats">
</div>

<div id="fordBlock" class="block" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" id="electric" placeholder="Electric"><br>
    <input type="text" id="consumption" placeholder="Fuel Consumption">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. :) That works perfectly fine, but I replaced the '${id}Block' expression with id+'Block'. The thing with the $ didn't worked and I've never used it either. What does that actually do? :D

Comment: It is called String Template and available in ES2015, which i thought, you are using because of the "let" ;)
In my opinion it is more readable if you have long or complex strings. Once you get used to it, you' ll use it even in very short strings ;) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Ah thanks. :) I am working with promises, which I think is ES7 oder higher!? But I've never used the string templates before, but they seem to be a very nice alternative. Now I am even more astonished, that this didn't worked. I'll give it another try later. :) Thanks again!